# Generating PDF via AJAX using mpdf

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, mpdf

I'm using the [mpdf library](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) to generate a PDF of user-generated html. I can get the PDF to save to the server successfully, but I want the PDF to open in the browser for the user. I've tried using mpdf's output options to open the file in the browser or to prompt a download, but neither happens when I use AJAX to send the html data to the script.

Here's my AJAX:

```
$('#save').click(function() {

        var shelf_clone = $('#shelf').clone();
        var shelf = shelf_clone.prop('outerHTML'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pdf.php",
            data: { html:shelf },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#status').html('File Saved Successfully');
            },
        })

    });
```

Here's my PDF-generating script:

```
<?php

include_once('/mpdf/mpdf.php');

$html = $_POST['html'];

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/print.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output('shelf.pdf', I);

exit;

?>
```

I'm using AJAX so that the PDF can be created without having to navigate away from the page. Is there an error in my code or should I be using a different approach?

Comment: some browsers doesn't view pdf file. Those will prompt download option to user. See http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up not using AJAX and instead added a hidden input on the form and populated it using the following script:

```
$('#save').click(function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var shelf_clone = $('#shelf').clone();
    var shelf = shelf_clone.prop('outerHTML');

    $('#save_shelf input[name=shelf]').val(shelf);

    $('#save_shelf').submit();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the browser

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf
```

To have the file downloaded rather than viewed

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename.pdf

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/pdf; charset=utf-8">
```

Or using **php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
header('Content-Description: inline; filename.pdf');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please clarify where I add these in my code? I tried appending them to the html data sent via ajax, but it had no affect.

Comment: @SajithaNilan how to do this using ajax?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani Did you try to send headers with Ajax?

Comment: @SajithaNilan how to do that?

Comment: Answer is incomplete.Please properly mention where and how the code should be added.