# Button in the view to save form as pdf with jquery-codeigniter-mpdf

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, button, mpdf

I'm trying to create a button in the view to save the form (empty) as a pdf, I've seen the mpdf library, but I can not get the form through the jquery to the driver to print it.

What I really want is to print an empty template of a form, maybe I do not need so much mess and maybe I create a pdf form by hand and put a button to download it, but my idea was to do it with different forms that are on the web and when you go to print, you can format it and be more elegant.

View(example1):

```
    <p><a id="printform" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><b>Save Pdf </b><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
<form action="" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name <span class="ast">*</span></label> 
          <div class="col-md-9 margen">
            <input tabindex="1" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Surname <span class="asterisco">*</span></label> 
          <div class="col-md-9 margen">
            <input tabindex="2" id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Adress <span class="ast">*</span></label> 
          <div class="col-md-9 margen">
            <input tabindex="4" id="adress" name="adress" type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <center>
          <div class="form-group">  
            <input tabindex="6" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm botonesmodales" value="Añadir" id="enviar" />
          </div>

    </form>
```

Controller(example)

```
public function printpdf()
{
    $data = [];
    //load the view and saved it into $html variable
    $html=$this->load->view('example1', $data, true);

    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";

    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');

   //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");       
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#printform', function(e){
 call controller...(How do I do it?)
});
```

Comment: you cannot call server's function at client side, you can use AJAX to do that.

Comment: Thanks Webinion, I use AJAX, but AJAX send content from input box but I don't know how do it for send only the html form, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating PDF via AJAX using mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776985/generating-pdf-via-ajax-using-mpdf)

Comment: Hi Finwe, is similar post share you, but I need call controller from html, exactly jquery, I need Ajax, but in the post you share not say how to do it in ajax.