# mpdf not working on ajax call (sending html from js to php)

Tags: javascript, php, mpdf

mpdf works fine on calling **url/ajax_pdf.php** directly

but not working on sending html via $.ajax from **url/ReportsInterface.js** -->**url/ajax_pdf.php**

no library or file include error . every last function of mdf is working fine

I have tried this code

js

```
function()
{

var html='<div><p>hello mpdf</p></div>';
$.ajax({
method : "POST",
url : "../common/ajax/ajax_pdf.php",
data : {html :html},
success:function(data){

console.log(data);
}
});

}
```

php

```
<?
    session_start();

    include('../../common/libs/mpdf/mpdf.php');

    if($_POST["html"])
{
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($_POST["html"]);
    $mpdf->Output($get_data->c_name.".pdf", 'I');
    $mpdf->Output();

}

?>
```

on console.log html and php contents are generating fine . but is not converting to pdf .. please suggest

Comment: Worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776985/generating-pdf-via-ajax-using-mpdf

Comment: Define "not working". Any errors in the console? HTTP status codes? Content-type of the response?

Comment: "not working" mean pd not generating

Comment: Where is `$get_data->c_name` defined?

Comment: Its always safer to use `<?php` that the short `<?`

Comment: Are you getting the parameter muddled? That looks like an `fpdf` method of outputting the result rather than an `mpdf` way